# Read data on NTFS Partition

Tags: ntfs, ubuntu-10.10

I had a Windows XP machine with an NTFS partion for programs (`C:\`) and I installed Ubuntu 10.10 on it. I will use Ubuntu from now on.

On the disk there was an NTFS partition and free space.

I created in the free space a new Linux partition. So the new Linux partition is a EXT3.

Now, from Ubuntu, I used the disk utility and saw that the Windows is marked as free space. I had only one possibility, which is to create a partition, so I did as NTFS.

I did NOT format it.

I don't care about the Windows system, I just need to access the program files folder on that partition and get my Chrome bookmarks. I forgot to save them before the installation of Linux.

Do you think it is possible? If so, how?

Comment: How to mount and read a NTFS volume in Ubuntu...http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/use-ubuntu-live-cd-to-backup-files-from-your-dead-windows-computer/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you re-partitioned your existing Windows NTFS partition in Linux, then it's gone. It might be possible to get the data back, you will need some recovery software that can recover from deleted partitions. I can't think of any off the top of my head.

Comment: thanks for the answer. partitioning does not clear the data. the danger is the format operation that I didn't do. I just need to find a utility under Linux that can read the particular space on the disk. It must read NTFS formatted data.

Comment: The data may not be physically erased from the platters, but the old NTFS is gone, and that was the only thing that knew where the files were stored on disk. How are you going to read the files from a disk without a file system if you don't use recovery software?

Comment: I don't know how to do it without the recovery software. do you know about such software that i could run from Linux?

Comment: A quick search turned up TestDisk http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk but that just mentions deleted partitions, not re-created ones.